# Why is balance-alb considered an invalid mode for high availability in a multi-switch topology?

Tags: linux, networking, bonding, high-availability

In the [Linux Ethernet Bonding Driver HOWTO](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt), section 11.2 describes a multi-switch topology for high availability, including a nice ASCII art diagram of such a setup that involves two switches with an inter-switch link (ISL) between them:

```
            |                                     |
            |port3                           port3|
      +-----+----+                          +-----+----+
      |          |port2       ISL      port2|          |
      | switch A +--------------------------+ switch B |
      |          |                          |          |
      +-----+----+                          +-----++---+
            |port1                           port1|
            |             +-------+               |
            +-------------+ host1 +---------------+
                     eth0 +-------+ eth1
```

The HOWTO then asserts that:

> In a topology such as the example above, the active-backup and
> broadcast modes are the only useful bonding modes when optimizing for
> availability; the other modes require all links to terminate on the
> same peer for them to behave rationally.

My question is: why wouldn't the `balance-alb` mode "behave rationally" in this topology?

I could see how `balance-alb` would tend to create congestion on the ISL if it were inadequately sized. If another host was connected only to switch A, for instance, the  balancing algorithm on host1 might direct traffic across the ISL rather than sending it over the more direct link between host1 and switch A.

But if the ISL had a significantly higher bandwidth capacity than the individual bonded connections, `balance-alb` would seem to give both high availability *and* increased bandwidth between hosts, which would be a "best of both worlds" scenario for high capacity, high availability clusters.

Are there other considerations that would make `balance-alb` a poor choice in this topology?